# draw a texture when i touch a specific texture in libgdx

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, textures, render

I am making a game with libgdx. if i touch the screen then a texture appears, but what i really want to do is that when i touch a specific texture then the other texture must appear.
this is my code for now:

```
public class MyGame extends InputAdapter implements ApplicationListener {

    SpriteBatch batch;

    Texture ball;
    Texture bat;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        ball = new Texture("ball.png");
        bat = new Texture("bat.png");
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        batch.begin();
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            batch.draw(ball, Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()
                    - Gdx.input.getY());
            batch.draw(bat, 50, 50);
            batch.end();

        }
    }
    }
```

it's not the whole code, just the code that is used to appear those textures.

I really appreciate your help.
Thankyou

Comment: In your current code 'batch.begin' is always called, but 'batch.end' is only called if there is a touch event. If you call 'batch.begin' you must always pair it with a call to 'batch.end' so the batch can be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below gives an example of how you can extend your current approach to test if the touch is within the area of your texture, but I would not recommend it for use in a real game.
It is fine as an exercise to understand what is going on, but manually coding the touch regions in this way will quickly become cumbersome as your game becomes more complex.
I would strongly recommend you become familiar with the scene2d package in libGdx. This package has methods to handle all the common 2D behaviors such as touch events, movement and collisions.
Like a lot of the libGdx library, the documentation can be hard to follow if you're just starting out, and there are not many tutorials around either. I'd recommend working through the [Java Game Development (LibGDX)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L) series of youtube videos by dermetfan. It helped me understand many areas when I was starting out. Good luck.

```
SpriteBatch batch;

Texture firstTexture;
Texture secondTexture;

float firstTextureX;
float firstTextureY;
float secondTextureX;
float secondTextureY;

float touchX;
float touchY;

@Override
public void create() {

    firstTexture= new Texture("texture1.png");
    firstTextureX = 50;
    firstTextureY = 50;

    secondTexture = new Texture("texture2.png");
    secondTextureX = 250;
    secondTextureY = 250;

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

}

@Override
public void render() {

    batch.begin; // begin the batch

    // draw our first texture
    batch.draw(firstTexture, firstTextureX, firstTextureY);

    // is the screen touched?
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {

        // is the touch within the area of our first texture?
        if (touchX > firstTextureX && touchX < (firstTextureX + firstTexture.getWidth())
                && touchY > firstTextureY && touchY < (firstTextureY + firstTexture.getHeight()) {
            // the touch is within our first texture so we draw our second texture
            batch.draw(secondTexture, secondTextureX, secondTextureY);
    }
    batch.end; // end the batch
}
```

Comment: Yh bro, i acctually don't know how to do that xD